# Is it WCF services VS ADO.NET Data Services?

Tags: wcf, web-services, ado.net, wcf-data-services

I only have vague idea of what WCF services are, but since most jobs for Asp.Net programmers ( those programming at Object data layer and Data access layer ) will  also require you to know WCF services, I will probably need to learn WCF services also. But then there’s also ADO.NET Data Services

1. Do the two technologies compete ( aka are meant to perform same tasks ) or at least overlap in some areas?
2. if they compete, which of the two would you recommend to learn?
3. Is one of them only used in very specific scenarios while other is used on a more regular basis ( I know I’m generalizing too much here :) )?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those two technologies DO NOT compete.

WCF is for developer writing services.

ADO.NET Data Services is for remotely hosting and querying your data.

Comment: thanx for clarification and sorry that I wasn't able to reply sooner